# Module "fluttertoast" not found

Tags: flutter

[GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:54:9 Module 'fluttertoast' not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo3p7.png)

I'm getting Module 'fluttertoast' not found i'm using MinimumOSVersion 11.0.

I'm trying to run my app in simulator